# Why is my Kotlin/JS program failing with "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"?

Tags: graalvm, kotlin-js, duktape

I’ve written a Kotlin/JS program that is crashing on some JavaScript engines.

It’s crashing on GraalVM like this:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at <js> 839(myprogram.js:394:1174923-1174934)
    at <js> e(myprogram.js:394:1175309-1175342)
    at <js> 724(myprogram.js:394:1174990-1174995)
    at <js> e(myprogram.js:394:1175309-1175342)
    at <js> :anonymous(myprogram.js:394:1175222-1175358)
    at <js> :program(myprogram.js:394:13041-1175382)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:345)
```

On Duktape it’s failing like this:

```
com.squareup.duktape.DuktapeException: RangeError: compiler recursion limit (line 1)
    at com.squareup.duktape.Duktape.evaluate(Native Method)
    at com.squareup.duktape.Duktape.evaluate(Duktape.java:60)
```

This crash was introduced by upgrading from Kotlin 1.4.10 to 1.6.21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin/JS uses a code shrinker in production builds. The code shrinker, [Terser](https://terser.org/), produces very long statements that exceed the default limits of certain compilers.

To fix this problem, configure Terser to produce smaller lines. Create a file, `subproject/webpack.config.d/myWebpackConfig.js` where *subproject* is the Gradle module that produces the Kotlin/JS executable.

In that file, paste the following:

```
config.optimization = config.optimization || {};
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
config.optimization.minimizer = [
    new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
            compress: {
                sequences: 10
            },
        },
    }),
];
```

Changing the value of the `sequences` option is the key. The default value, 200, fits 200 logical statements into each line. By scaling this down to 10 Terser emits smaller statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and start the Java VM with the `-Xss` and provide more stack to it, the default seems not to be enough for your usecase.

`-Xss8m` (or more)